# VBA: Show listbox on click

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, show, visible

I searched for a way to show a listbox on certain event, here a click, but wasn't able to find it

```
 If MsgBox("Souhaitez vous reprendre un bordereau déjà édité?", vbYesNo, "Edition Bordereau") = vbYes Then
 PreCheckPlot
 Else
rest of commands
```

And the sub where I want to show the listbox

```
Sub PreCheckPlot()
ListBox2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This doesn't work, and `ListBox2.Show` doesn't either, it throws an error.

Is it possible to show a listbox on a click, and if yes, how would I write it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the Sheet as well.

So if your `ListBox2` is in Sheet1 then you need to use:

```
 Sheet1.ListBox2.Visible = True
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does it go into PreCheckPlot when you step through?
What is the error?

If you create a userform, put a listbox on it and a button which when pressed shows your message your code then works fine.

I wonder if you are trying to set ListBox2.Visible from outside the form (where it will not know what the form is)

This assumes it is an ActiveX listbox - or is it a forms listbox?

Comment: Yes, it does go through PreCheckPlot, but it doesn't do anything. the error with .show method is error 424: required object..
it is an ActiveX listbox

Comment: so is it an active x listbox on an Excel worksheet?

What worksheet event are you trying to use to trigger it?

Comment: Yes, ActiveX listbox on an excel worksheet, the same where the button triggers the event. It's all on the same worksheet. Do I need to specify the ws in the sub?

Comment: Yes, that was that. I specified the ws of listbox, and it worked, with the .visible method. Thanks